# Riemann Integration and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: integration, axiom-of-choice

In Riemann's definition of integration in $[a,b]$, a step in the process consists of choosing one point from each part of the "current" partition for further a partition, and again choose one point from each part where the function will be evaluated.

Is this mathematically\logically possible without the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: At any step there is a finite number of choices needing to be made, and anyways, choosing the middle point almost always works out, so I don't think there's any need for AC in that case.

Comment: @Arthur systematically taking the middle point takes the beauty out of the definition... :)

Comment: True, but it seemed like you wanted to know whether there were a choice function, and I gave you one.

Comment: @Arthur *Now* I understand why/what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axiom of choice is not needed at all. Note that the integral is defined as a limit over finite partitions. Moreover these partitions are partitions into intervals, so the partitions themselves are simplistic as well.

The partition are finite, so there is no need to worry about the existence of choice functions, and we don't choose a particular sequence of partitions. We consider **all** of them.

And as the old saying goes, if you don't know what to choose - take everything.

Comment: When you come to a fork in the road...

Comment: You bring a knife and a spoon!

Comment: ...I fall and eat dirt while trying to pull the fork out of the tarmac.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have a feeling I should be offended by these comments?

Comment: @Dror: How's that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila too complicated to answer that. Never-mind :)